# call stored procedure in vb script

Tags: stored-procedures, vbscript, ado

I have created a stored procedure. I tested it in the query analyser like this EXEC test '10/12/2012'. It is OK. But I called it following way in the vb script. It not OK.

```
InstanceVar = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
InstanceVar.ActiveConnection = ConnVar
InstanceVar.Source = "EXEC Test '" & Date() & "'"
InstanceVar.CursorType = 3
InstanceVar.CursorLocation = 3
InstanceVar.Open()
```

I have got 80040E14 error. How can I solve it

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit late, but I found this question when looking for a solution to the same problem.  I've solved it like this:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = ConnVar
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "Test"
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("@my_date", adVarChar, adParamInput,10))
cmd.Parameters("@my_date") = "10/12/2012"

Set rsResults = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsResults.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsResults.Open cmd,,adOpenForwardOnly,adLockBatchOptimistic
```

Using `CursorLocation = adUseClient` means you can navigate the `rsResults` RecordSet using `MoveNext`, `MoveFirst` etc.